# How do I use absolute and relative imports in python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-import

I have a python project/library called "slingshot" with the following directory structure:

```
slingshot/
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
    build.py
    deploy.py
    util/
        __init__.py
        prepare_env.py
        cdn_api.py
```

From `__main__.py` I would like to import functions from `util/prepare_env.py`.

I would like to ensure that `util` refers to the `util` I have in my project, and not some other `util` library that may be installed somewhere.

I tried `from .util import prepare_env` but I get an error.

`from util import prepare_env` seems to work, but doesn't address the ambiguity of "util".

What am I doing wrong?

---

`__main__.py` is as follows:

```
import os
from .util import prepare_env

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if 'SLINGSHOT_INITIALIZED' not in os.environ:
        prepare_env.pip_install_requirements()
        prepare_env.stub_travis()
        prepare_env.align_branches()
        os.environ['SLINGSHOT_INITIALIZED'] = 'true'
```

When I type `python3 ./slingshot` I get the following error:

```
  File "./slingshot/__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .util import prepare_env
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

When I type `python3 -m ./slingshot` I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6: Relative module names not supported
```

Comment: Please share the error you get, and how you start your `__main__.py` script.

Comment: You need to run `python3 -m slingshot` (no `./` prefix).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`__main__.py` modules in a package make the module run as a script when you use the `-m` command line switch. That switch takes a *module name*, not a path, so drop the `./` prefix:

```
python3 -m slingshot
```

The current working directory is added to the start of the module search path so `slingshot` is found first, no need to give a relative path specification here.

From the [`-m` switch documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m):

> Search `sys.path` for the named module and execute its contents as the `__main__` module.
>
> Since the argument is a *module* name, you must not give a file extension (`.py`). The module name should be a valid absolute Python module name[.]
>
> [...]
>
> As with the `-c` option, the current directory will be added to the start of `sys.path`.